# Как организовать импорт макросов в Excel на C#

Tags: c#, excel, vba

В институте на производственной практике дали задание - написать своего рода инсталлятор с опциями импорта-экспорта макросов в Excel. Сделал реализацию через импорт макроса в Персональную книгу макросов:

```
var App = new Excel.Application { Visible = false };
var PersonalWorkBook = App.Workbooks.Open($"{System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)}\\Microsoft\\Excel\\XLSTART\\PERSONAL.XLSB");
PersonalWorkBook.VBProject.VBComponents.Import(FileName);
PersonalWorkBook.Save();
App.Quit();
```

Но этот вариант не прошел на фирме, из-за политик безопасности обращения к Персональной книге пресекаются.
Теперь оказался в тупике, не знаю, как еще это можно реализовать.
В целом, работу программы можно описать так:

1. В программу добавляют макросы, вводят их описание, получают некую библиотеку макросов.
2. Сотрудник IT отдела приходит с этой программой к пользователю, выбирает нужные ему макросы и импортирует их к нему в пару кликов.

Пример оформления программы:

[image: Пример оформления программы]

Comment: может просто сохранять в программе макросы в виде текста , 
при выборе макроса в программе копировать этот текст в буфер обмена , и далее уже добавлять этот текст куда то пользователю ... туда , куда позволят ваши политики , может возможно эти макросы использовать в виде надстроек для экселя ...

Comment: `Но этот вариант не прошел на фирме, из-за политик безопасности обращения к Персональной книге пресекаются.` вы это проверяли с правами сотрудника ИТ?

Comment: Разрабатываете и сохраняете макросы в отдельной книге/книгах. Эти книги сохраняете как надстройки и добавляете пользователям нужные. Ничего программировать не нужно, это стандартная функция excel. Правда нужно помнить, что такие макросы будут доступны пользователю в любом файле excel. Если это устраивает - проблемы нет.

Comment: @sp7 да, Персональная книга макросов доступна только для чтения...

Comment: @rdorn в том то и проблема, что макросы уже разработаны. Нужно структуризировать их в одну библиотеку и оптимизировать процесс установки.

Comment: ну ок, если уже разработаны, значит просто группируем их по надстройкам и распространяем среди пользователей, можно даже средствами AD, тогда и ходить никому ни куда не придется, добавляешь нужный файл в групповую политику и при логине пользователя все подтянется. И все же вы не ответили - устроит ли вариант доступности макросов в любом файле в пределах пользовательской машины, или нужно обязательно в конкретный файл добавлять?

Comment: @rdorn макросы должны быть доступны из любого файла. Как я понял это реализуется либо через персональную книгу, либо через те же надстройки. Проблема остается в том, что каждому пользователю видимо нужен уникальный набор макросов и нужно, чтобы программа генерировала соответствующую надстройку для конкретного пользователя.